# Group by with getting only max value

Tags: sql, sql-server, join, group-by

I have three tables

- **machine** *(list of machines)*,
- **event** *(list of machine events eg. event id, machine name, start and stop timetamp)*
- and **eventdetails** *(more information about every event specified by event id and machine name)*.

I want to execute a query, which joins the data of max event id for every machine, but I have some problems with grouping.

**Table machine:**

```
machine
-----------
Machine 1
Machine 2
```

**Table event:**

```
eventid | machine   | start      | stop
-----------------------------------------------
      1 | Machine 1 | 2016-06-14 | 2016-06-16
      2 | Machine 1 | 2016-06-16 | null
      1 | Machine 2 | 2016-05-30 | null
```

**Table eventdetails:**

```
eventid | machine   | name       | value
-----------------------------------------------
      1 | Machine 1 | product    | Product 1
      1 | Machine 1 | person     | Samuel
```

I have tried following query, but it returns more than one row per machine... I want to group by machine and get only data according to max event id.

```
SELECT m.machine, MAX(e.eventid), e.start, e.stop, d.name, d.value
FROM machine m 
JOIN event e ON e.machine = m.machine
JOIN eventdetails d ON d.eventid = e.eventid AND d.machine = m.machine
GROUP BY m.machine, e.start, e.stop, d.name, d.value
```

Thanks in advance.

Comment: SQL Server??MySQL?

Comment: @SateeshPagolu SQL Server

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Give this one a go. It gives you an inner join that will suppress anything from the `event` table what doesn't equal the `max(eventid)` from the same table.

```
SELECT m.machine, e.eventid, e.start, e.stop, d.name, d.value
FROM machine m 
INNER JOIN event e ON e.machine = m.machine
INNER JOIN eventdetails d ON d.eventid = e.eventid AND d.machine = m.machine
INNER JOIN (SELECT machine, MAX(eventid) maxevent FROM event GROUP BY machine) ma ON m.machine = ma.machine AND e.eventid = ma.maxevent
GROUP BY m.machine, e.start, e.stop, d.name, d.value
```

Comment: I was assuming that OP was comfortable with the syntax as it matches his other joins in the supplied code. But yes, in SQL Server these will be inner joins, i'll update my answer.